# How to make an HTTP POST from Flutter to a local cloud functions server

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

How do I make a POST request from a Flutter application on  Android to a Firebase cloud functions server running locally?

Here is my code:

```
{
  print("good email");
  String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/mattsapp/api1'; //I have also tried replacing this with localhost
  String json = '{"email": "a@gmail.com", "username": "user1", "password":"111111"}';

  Future<void> loginPost() async {
    http.Response resp = await http.post(url, body: json);
    print(resp);
  }
  loginPost();
}
```

When I run the code the connection times out.  When I replace `10.0.2.2` with `localhost`, I get the following error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 58912
```

When I run with Postman to `http://localhost:5000/mattsapp/api1` it works fine.

Comment: Try adding a header to your request headers: HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Hi @Federick Jonathan.  How do I do that.  Do I just add it in the post request.  For example: await http.post(url, body: json, header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Comment: http.post(url, body: json, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},). My bad, headers is supposed to receive Map

Comment: It's still not working.  It's still running and is just going to time out.

Comment: Yeah, it just timed out.

Comment: Um.. I'm not sure because I experienced the same thing before but by adding a headers it solved the issue

Comment: Thanks though @Frederick Jonathan I appreciate it!

Comment: Have you added internet permissions to your `manifest.json`?

Comment: Hi @sudo_kaizen, thanks for helping out?  How exactly would I go about doing this?  In which manifest.json folder?

Comment: Hi @Frederick Jonathan and sudo_kaizen.  Could it be because I didn't register my app with firebase?  I was thinking if I was making http requests it wouldn't matter but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi guys.  Adding an android project did not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [connect_functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions) and this [clear_text_traffic_permitted](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

> Applications intending to connect to destinations using only secure connections can opt-out of supporting cleartext (using the unencrypted HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS) to those destinations. This option helps prevent accidental regressions in apps due to changes in URLs provided by external sources such as backend servers.

create a xml file `/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml` and put the code in the file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

navigate to AndroidManifest.xml in main folder: `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

add networkSecurityConfig in application tag like below :

```xml
 <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        ...
 </application>
```

Note: This does not work on a real device but works on an emulator. If you want to use a real device, you need to replace `10.0.0.2` to other ip address such as hotspot or wifi in the network_security_config.xml.